# Scrapy Xpath Query ( Scraping from Similar Class but different align tags)

Tags: xpath, scrapy

The code from where I want to scrape my data:

```
<td class="pageHeading" valign="top">ABC<br><span class="smallText">[RK103401]</span></td>
            <td class="pageHeading" align="right" valign="top">SAMPLE2<br>
```

I want to know the Xpath which will lead me to extract SAMPLE2.

I notice that the class name is the same but can't figure out how to go about this.

Thanks!

Comment: //td[@class='pageHeading']/text()

But that gives all the values. Just need Sample2

Comment: You want "Sample2" based on what criterion? the text value itself? some data before? a position of the `td` in the parent `table`?

Comment: I just require the text.

Answer (score 0):

When looking for an XPath to select something specific, you want to find an element that is unique to what you want to catch. Here, it's pretty hard to tell as there aren't much HTML, so we don't know which elements won't be repeated throughout the doc.

Something like this might do the trick:

```
//td[class="pageHeading" and align="right"]/text()
```